# Write to Random Access File in Java without overwriting

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

In a Random Access File, at a particular byte position, the new text to be inserted is overwritten. How do I modify the `write` method so that the new text is inserted between the existing values without overwriting?

I know it is possible to shift but I 'know how the logic. Please help me with the logic

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  That is not the way that random access files work.  That is not how files work **in general**.

If you want to insert characters into a file you need to rewrite the file.  The safe way is to do this by writing a new file with a temporary name, containing the updated contents, then delete the old one and rename the temporary file.

---

> I know it is possible to shift but I 'know how the logic.

Firstly, "shifting" involves overwriting the characters after the insertion point.

Secondly, "shifting" is a dangerous operation.  If the application is interrupted, or the system fails / is powered off while you are in the middle of the "shift" operation, you are liable to corrupt the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as in C: you can't, the filesystem doesn't allow that.
see:
[C function to insert text at particular location in file without over-writing the existing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033060/c-function-to-insert-text-at-particular-location-in-file-without-over-writing-th)