# What is mode of file pointer?

Tags: c, file-pointer

What's mode pointer is what mode, `'insert'` or `overwrite`?

Because I'm new to `file pointer` in C, so maybe my question is quite stupid. I'm sorry if anyone feels that.

And what I  could do if I want to `insert some character` into existen file but don't lose any character in this file.

Comment: Frankly, I did not understand your question. What mode?

Comment: Do you mean *read*, *write* , *append* mode?

Comment: It is not controlled by C itself, When you `scanf()` or `fgets()` control is transferred to the Operating System.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation to `fopen()`.

Comment: @pmg - this is not true due to the use of a buffer

Comment: @EdHeal ... and that buffer gets filled with data from the Operating System.

Comment: It does not always get transferred as implied by your comment

Comment: With the update to the question it now tends to be a duplicate to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2431073/694576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No file systems I know of support *insert* mode.

The C semantics for writing to file streams is either:

- truncation for `"w"`. The current file contents is lost upon successful `fopen()`.
- overwriting file contents for `"r+"`.  Only byte written explicitly to the file will overwrite existing contents, the rest is unchanged.  Writing beyond the end of the file will extend its size, just like append mode.
- appending to file for `"a"`.  Every write operation occurs at the end of file.

Note that `"w"` and `"a"` will also create the file is it does not exist.

In order to *insert* contents in the middle of an existing file, you must copy the contents to a new file, writing the new contents at the appropriate positions.  You can rename the new file to the old name after closing both and removing the old one.

Comment: @DDK:  Can you please click the grey check mark below to answer score to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you open it:

To append:

```
fopen("myfile.txt", "a");
```

To write (overwrite):

```
fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
```

Comment: Implying "appending" could "insert" is misleading. In general "inserting" is not possible.

Comment: @alk Perhaps, edited. However, in the general view of "insertion" vs "overwriting" a part of me said that OP probably meant appending.

Comment: `"w"` does not allow partial overwriting of file contents, the output file is truncated to `0` length or created if it does not exist

Comment: @chrqlie Yes, overwriting the file.

Comment: @JameyD: *overwriting* is ambiguous.  If you intend to overwrite say the fifth byte of the file and leave the rest untouched, `"w"` is inappropriate, `"r+"` should be used.  The OP uses *insert* and *overwrite* modes as in a text editor.