# Change one line, rewrite whole file?

Tags: filesystems

Simple question about how file system works.

If I change one line in 100MB .txt file, will the file system invalid and rewrite whole 100MB of file?

What if I add one line? (and file size changes)

Thanks.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? I don't think any will re-write the _entire_ file, but depending on the filesystem and the storage medium, they may be forced to re-write/move around some pieces.

Comment: @wolfson Well that's what I thought... General file system such as _ext_ _xfs_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesystem doesn't have a notion of writing to the middle of the file -- it only knows how to append to the end. In C, if you want to write data to the middle of a file, you need to [manually move forward all the data past the point at which you want to write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431073/how-do-i-insert-and-delete-some-characters-in-the-middle-of-a-file), then write the new characters to the newly created space.

In doing this, it's possible that the filesystem will have to rearrange parts of the file, for instance if you exceed the size of the disk block that that piece of the file is stored on. So everything **at and past the point where you're adding text to the middle** has to be re-written, but **where** it's re-written depends on the filesystem and the arrangement of the file on disk.

TL;DR it depends on the filesystem and how the file was stored on disk.

Comment: Thanks. There should be beautiful way to rearrange updated files.